# Плавный sticky header для шапки с произвольной высотой

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap

Использую bootstrap 3.

В контенте шапка состоит из 3-х уровней: `.header-top`, `.header-nav`, `.header-bottom`

`.header-top` и `.header-bottom` с произвольным контентом, разной высоты. Т.е. фиксированную высоту нельзя задать.

`.header-nav` можно задать фикс. высоту, но не желательно тоже.

При добавлении класса `sticky` шапка должна плавно цепляться к верху странички, при этом `.header-top` и `.header-bottom` плавно сварачиваются.

Пытаюсь сделать так:

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {

  var st = $('.header').offset().top;

  if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 100){
    $('.header').addClass("sticky");
  }
  else{
    $('.header').removeClass("sticky"); 
  }

});
```

```css
.header-top {
  padding: 1rem 0;
  background: #ccc;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.header-bottom {
  background: #555;
  padding: 2rem 0;
  color:#eee;
}

.content {
  height: 3000px;
  border:1px solid #000;
  padding: 1rem;
  font-size:1.5rem;
  line-height: 2.5rem;
  color:#333;
}

main {
  padding: 1rem 0;;
}

.footer {
  background: #000;
  color:#fff;
  padding: .5rem 0;;
}






.header.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1000;

}

.header.sticky .header-top,
.header.sticky .header-bottom {
  height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  
<div class="header">
  <div class="header-top text-center">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          Top Header
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="header-nav">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li> 
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
  
  <div class="header-bottom text-center">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          Header bottom
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  
  
<main>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="content">
          <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1509118988680-4c14bd0ff4de?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=99f5f5bf98fc0f9d4f6142bc12f5742c&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="" class="img-responsive">
          
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur, optio?
          </p>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse illum voluptates modi corporis tenetur mollitia sunt vitae natus consequuntur quae.
          </p>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos asperiores culpa ea ex dicta recusandae!
          </p>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora, quisquam quos quidem illum ullam. Itaque, ducimus magni tenetur corporis aliquid accusamus quod a animi hic rem fugiat, est, suscipit. Sunt!
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
  
<footer class="footer text-center">
  <div class="conteiner">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        Footer
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Проблема: плавность отсутствует и самое главное - прыгает страничка (по жирафу хорошо заметно).

**Вопрос:** Как сделать анимированую шапку странички из 3-х уровней при этом устранить прыжки страницы при добавлении класса `sticky` ?

---

**UPDATE**

---

Если задавать отступ у `body`:

```js
var elementPosition = $('.header').offset();
var elementheight = $(".header").height();

$(window).scroll(function(){
        if($(window).scrollTop() > elementPosition.top){
              $('.header').addClass("sticky");
              $("body").css({
                "paddingTop": elementheight
              });
              
          //$('.header-top, .header-bottom').slideUp();
        } else {
            $('.header').removeClass("sticky");
            $("body").css({
              "paddingTop":"0"
            });
          //$('.header-top, .header-bottom').slideDown();
        }    
});
```

```css
.header-top .col-md-12 {
  padding-top: 1rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  background: #ccc;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.header-bottom .col-md-12 {
  background: #555;
  padding-top: 2rem;
  padding-bottom: 2rem;
  color:#eee;
}

.content {
  height: 3000px;
  border:1px solid #000;
  padding: 1rem;
  font-size:1.5rem;
  line-height: 2.5rem;
  color:#333;
}

main {
  padding: 1rem 0;;
}

.footer {
  background: #000;
  color:#fff;
  padding: .5rem 0;;
}






.header.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1000;

}

.header.sticky .header-top,
.header.sticky .header-bottom {
  height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  
<div class="header">
  <div class="header-top text-center">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          Top Header
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="header-nav">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li> 
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
  
  <div class="header-bottom text-center">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          Header bottom
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  
  
<main>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="content">
          <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1509118988680-4c14bd0ff4de?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=99f5f5bf98fc0f9d4f6142bc12f5742c&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="" class="img-responsive">
          
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur, optio?
          </p>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse illum voluptates modi corporis tenetur mollitia sunt vitae natus consequuntur quae.
          </p>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos asperiores culpa ea ex dicta recusandae!
          </p>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora, quisquam quos quidem illum ullam. Itaque, ducimus magni tenetur corporis aliquid accusamus quod a animi hic rem fugiat, est, suscipit. Sunt!
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
  
<footer class="footer text-center">
  <div class="conteiner">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        Footer
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Получается такой отступ:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: для body в то время когда header фиксируется задать padding-top равный высоте header.. я уже задавал этот вопрос ...

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, а ссылочку можно на Ваш вопрос?

Comment: там не много другое но суть одна и таже .. в тот момент когда что то становится fixed и top 0 естественно что то что ниже прыгает вверх и потому самое рациональное решение задать для body именно в этот момент padding-top равный высоте элемента

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут проблема в том что когда элемент фиксируется то содержимое попадает под него и происходит скачок ... вот так можно выйти из этой ситуации

```js
var elementPosition = $('header').offset();
var elementheight = $("header").height();

$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > elementPosition.top) {
    $('header').addClass("fixed");
    $("body").css({
      "paddingTop": elementheight
    })
  } else {
    $('header').removeClass("fixed");
    $("body").css({
      "paddingTop": "0"
    })
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 1000px;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  background: tomato;
}

header.fixed {
  height: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header></header>
<div class="elem">
  некий контент с соджержимым
</div>



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: а тут, если для моего примера применять, когда добавляется класс fixed остается пустое пространство между меню и контентом. Для body отступ равен всей высоте меню (с header-top+header-bottom), а само меню без верха и низа намного меньше по высоте

Comment: Лена вы заметили то я не указывал высоту , т.е можно уменьшить или разделить .. но по крайней мере скачка не будет ...